# How to remove notice at login

Tags: 4.7, 4.6, civicrm.settings.php, ux

When users login right now (Jan 4, 2018) they get a notice publicising CiviCamp 2018.  For 99% of users this notice is inappropriate. How do I remove it?  I know it can be removed via some update to civicrm settings file but can't find how to do this.

Answer (score 6):

This is a preference you can set, but it's not exposed in the web interface.  There's a section of `civicrm.settings.php` that documents it.  In case you've upgraded from an older version of CiviCRM that doesn't have it, I'm including it here:

```
 // Opt-out of announcements by the CiviCRM core team for releases, paid services, events, etc. Separate each preferred optout category with a comma:                                                              
 //   "offers": paid service offers                 
 //   "asks": requests for donations or membership signup/renewal to CiviCRM                             
 //   "releases": major release announcements       
 //   "events": announcements of local/national upcoming events                                          
 $civicrm_setting['CiviCRM Preferences']['communityMessagesUrl'] = 'https://alert.civicrm.org/alert?prot=1&ver={ver}&uf={uf}&sid={sid}&lang={lang}&co={co}&optout=offers,asks';
```

More documentation is available at in the [CiviCRM Administration Guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/), see page [Customization > Override Settings](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/settings/).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Jon G for providing the solution to turn off the community messages.

However, as one of the organizers of CiviCamp Brussels 2018, I am very happy with this feature. It's an effective way to reach civi users who are not on your own mailing lists and who might otherwise miss the event.

They would miss an opportunity to engage with the community. And the community is an essential aspect of open source software. Even if the event is not in their area, at least they realize that civi users get together to share knowledge and exchange ideas.

Comment: There is already a "CiviCRM News" dashlet that AFAIK is enabled by default in new installs and easily manageable via the UI. This community messages "feature" should also have an explicit (i.e. in the UI) switch in my view. Without that, it might be perceived by some users as enforced advertising, especially where the message being communicated is perceived as irrelevant.